# Extending inner for loop calls indefinitely

Tags: c, for-loop, recursion

The following code snippet will print every 4 character long combination (without repetition) of the elements of an array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++)
        for (int k = j + 1; k < len; k++)
            for (int l = k + 1; l < len; l++)
                printf("%c%c%c%c\n", arr[i], arr[j], arr[k], arr[l]);
```

My problem is I don't know how to extend this to a general function (ie print every N character long combination). How can I make a function do the same thing but be called like this:

```
combinationPrint(array, numberOfForLoops); // With other params if needed
```

Comment: What does your failed attempt look like?

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example._

Comment: try searching for : **all permutations of a given string** , maybe this might help : http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/

Comment: @melpomene, let's just say there's a reason it isn't posted..

Comment: @NawarIsmail You said you made a recursive attempt.  Seeing that attempt, even if not working, is useful for others to see so that we can tell what your thought process was, where it went wrong, and try to correct it.  Demonstrating to you how to think about the problem is more useful than just showing you the code that does it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recursive version of your function would work like this:

```
void recur (char* arr, int i, int len, char *x, int k, int n) {
    if (k==n) {   // the last inner loop
        x[k]=0; 
        printf ("%s\n", x);
    }
    else {   
        for (int j=i+1; j<len; j++) { // recursive loop
            x[k]=arr[j];
            recur (arr, j, len, x, k+1, n);  // call recursion for an inner loop
        }
    }
}
```

In this recursion, `arr` and `len` correspond to your definition and n is the depth of the loops you want to achieve (4 in your non recursive version).

The trick is to use a null terminated array of n+1 chars, that you keep across the recursion and build the string that you want to print at the last level.  i is then the starting position of the loop and k is the current level of recursion.

You would call this:

```
recur (arr, -1, len, out, 0, 4 );
```

**[Online demo](http://ideone.com/FVIbbz)**

Answer (score 2):

Without recursion, you can use this (len = length of the array) :

```
int i, j, w, x;
for(i=0; i<pow(len,len); i++){ //n^n possibilities / combinaisons
    w = i;
    for(j=0; j<len; j++){ //Show the combinaison
        x = w%len; //We have juste to calculate the correct position with some modulos
        printf("%c", array[x]);
        w = w/len;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

For exemple with this implementation :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

    int array[] = {1,2,3};

    int len = 3;
    int i, j, w, x;
    for(i=0; i<pow(len,len); i++){
                w = i;
                for(j=0; j<len; j++){
                        x = w%len;
                        printf("%d", array[x]);
                        w = w/len;
                }
    printf("\n%d\n", i);
    }

}
```

You should have :

```
111
211
311
121
221 [...]
133
233
333
```

Comment: This is great, but the code snippet I put up gave the result without repeating numbers (ie only one 1, one 2, ...) is there a way to modify your function to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, instead of N loops - you just need one. Within this main loop you have to have just two inner loops for incrementing array of indices and for printing values:

```
int increment(int* index, int N, int len)
{
    for (int i = N - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        ++index[i];
        if (index[i] < len)
            return 1;
        index[i] = 0;
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

So - the main loop:

```
    int index[N] = {};

    do
    {
        // print
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            printf("%c", arr[index[i]]);
        printf("\n");
    } while (increment(index, N, len));
```